# Which equality test does Ruby's Hash use when comparing keys?

Tags: ruby, hash, equals, equality

I have a wrapper class around some objects that I want to use as keys in a Hash. The wrapped and unwrapper objects should map to the same key.

A simple example will be this:

```
class A
  attr_reader :x
  def initialize(inner)
    @inner=inner
  end
  def x; @inner.x; end
  def ==(other)
    @inner.x==other.x
  end
end
a = A.new(o)  #o is just any object that allows o.x
b = A.new(o)
h = {a=>5}
p h[a] #5
p h[b] #nil, should be 5
p h[o] #nil, should be 5
```

I've tried ==, ===, eq? and hash all to no avail.

Comment: You might want to look into `SimpleDelegator`, if you want to delegate most methods to `@inner`.

Comment: Thanks @Marc-AndréLafortune! Learnt something new today

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Hash uses key.eql? to test keys for equality. If you need to use
>   instances of your own classes as keys in a Hash, it is recommended
>   that you define both the eql? and hash methods. The hash method must
>   have the property that a.eql?(b) implies a.hash == b.hash.

So...

```
class A
  attr_reader :x
  def initialize(inner)
    @inner=inner
  end
  def x; @inner.x; end
  def ==(other)
    @inner.x==other.x
  end

  def eql?(other)
    self == other
  end

  def hash
    x.hash
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah, so it uses both. Now that I think about it, makes sense to use `hash` to get the bucket then `eql?` for the actual test. I think it's the same in Java too

Comment: But why default implementation of `eq?` doesn't use `==`?

Answer (score 5):

You must define `eql?` and `hash`.

The documentation of `Hash` was lacking but [has been improved recently](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L3292).