# Hash lookup fails when set key and lookup pass an equality test

Tags: ruby, hash

I can not reproduce this problem in new code, but it appears very consistently.

Given the following data:

```
[47] pry> t
=> [Fri, 01 Mar 2013 00:00:00 +0000, Sun, 24 Mar 2013 23:59:59 +0000]
[48] pry> time_range
=> [Fri, 01 Mar 2013 00:00:00 +0000, Sun, 24 Mar 2013 23:59:59 +0000]
[49] pry> t == time_range
=> true
[52] pry> hsh
=> {[Fri, 01 Mar 2013 00:00:00 +0000, Sun, 24 Mar 2013 23:59:59 +0000]=> {},
 [Fri, 01 Feb 2013 00:00:00 +0000, Thu, 28 Feb 2013 23:59:59 +0000]=> {},
 [Tue, 01 Jan 2013 00:00:00 +0000, Thu, 31 Jan 2013 23:59:59 +0000]=> {}}
```

This is the problem I have when doing a lookup:

```
[53] pry> hsh[t]
=> {}
[54] pry> hsh[time_range]
=> nil
[55] pry> hsh.assoc(time_range)
=> [[Fri, 01 Mar 2013 00:00:00 +0000, Sun, 24 Mar 2013 23:59:59 +0000],
 {}]
```

Two arrays of times (`t`, and `time_range`) pass an equality test with `==`, but fail to look up the value in only one case (time_range). I have tried looking into the Hash code (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) but am still stumped.

According to "[Which equality test does Ruby's Hash use when comparing keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247000/which-equality-test-does-rubys-hash-use-when-comparing-keys)", hash uses `eql?` to determine key equality but the two offending keys pass `eql?`:

```
[63] pry> t.eql? time_range
=> true
[64] pry> time_range.eql? t
=> true
```

Can anyone offer insight? Right now I'm going to rework my code to utilize the assoc match, but I don't like doing things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on those links, is hash for both objects identical?

We've had issues in a multithreaded JRuby environment where keys in two separate runtimes satisfy == but fail to retrieve keys due to differing object_ids of the underlying keys.
It could be a similar class of problem - two objects A and B which satisfy A.eql? B but do not satisfy A is B

Comment: Which has are you referring to as being identical? For info I am using MRI ruby 1.9.3p327 on windows. The issue is occurring on our prod Linux boxes too.

Comment: the hash method, which is also used for equality checking.  Check http://techbot.me/2011/05/ruby-basics-equality-operators-ruby/ - I'm unsure if this is still current but it is an avenue you could check.

Comment: `hash` inequality isn't the problem as `t` has the same `hash` as `hsh.keys.first.hash`: `t.hash => -3958758151071268050` and `hsh.keys.first.hash => -3958758151071268050`. `hsh.keys.first.hash
== t.hash => true`