# How to overwrite ruby Hash#[] key compare?

Tags: ruby, hash

How to overwrite ruby Hash#[] key compare?

```
class FooBar
  def uid
    "123"  
  end
  alias_method :to_s, :uid

  def ==(other)
    self.uid == other.uid
  end
  alias_method :eql?, :==
end

class Foo < FooBar
end

class Bar < FooBar
end

Foo.new == Bar.new # returns true
Hash[[Foo.new,"succcess"]][Bar.new] # should return "succcess"
Hash[[Foo.new,"succcess"]].has_key? Bar.new # should return true
```

Comment: I almost submitted an answer about implementing [`Comparable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Comparable.html), but I'm not sure if that is what you need/want.

Comment: Hey @user2422869, thanks for trying to improve the question, but please be careful when editing such that you don't inadvertently fix the problem being asked about! If you can identify the problem facing the asker, post an answer instead - that way, the question + answer have a chance of helping someone else making the same mistake in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You were close. You also needed to redefine `hash`. And you had an extra pair of brackets in your Hash creation. The following works:

```
class FooBar
  def uid
    "123"  
  end
  alias_method :to_s, :uid

  def ==(other)
    self.uid == other.uid
  end
  alias_method :eql?, :==

  def hash
    uid.hash
  end

end

class Foo < FooBar
end

class Bar < FooBar
end

Foo.new == Bar.new # returns true
Hash[Foo.new,"succcess"][Bar.new] # returns "succcess"
Hash[Foo.new,"succcess"].has_key? Bar.new # returns true
```

See [Which equality test does Ruby's Hash use when comparing keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247000/which-equality-test-does-rubys-hash-use-when-comparing-keys) for additional discussion.